# Getting elements from table row within different tables with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i need help with returning some elements from tr with javascript(jquery)

**Question 1.**
How can i reach td where is comment *"i need to get to this item (based on question1)"*? So i need to get last item with class "b" and first td that comes after it? Number of td's is not static. Classes b may not be in same table.

**Question 2.**
Also if I want to select class "a" and give next 5 (for example) td's some class ("b" for example) how can i do it? Function nextAll can help but it will only get elements from single row.

Example is below:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td class="a"></td>
  <td></td> <!-- this needs to get class b -->
  <td></td> <!-- this needs to get class b -->
  <td></td> <!-- this needs to get class b -->
</tr>
</table>

<table>
<tr>
  <td></td> <!-- this needs to get class b -->
  <td></td> <!-- this needs to get class b -->
  <td></td> <!-- i need to get to this item (based on question1) -->
  <td></td>
  <td></td> 
  <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Thanks

Comment: $('td').nextAll('.a:lt('+X+')').addClass('b'); will get X elements but from single row, i need to combine multiple rows and even combine tables, so this method stops on last td in row and doesn't help.
not sure how to get item after last element with class b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("td.b:last").html(); // to get content of last td with class b 

    $("td.b:last").next("td").html(); // to get first td after b class 

    // for a 

    $("td.a:first").slice(5).addClass("b");
 });
 </script>
```

> See Reference **[:last](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)** , **[:first](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)** and **[slice()](https://api.jquery.com/slice/)**

New edit

```
  $("table.someclass").each(function(){
        $(this).find("td.a:first").nextAll("td").addClass("b");
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, but how did you get td.b:first since there is no class "b" yet?

Comment: it was typing mistake it should be `a`

Comment: slice didn't help, not sure why

Comment: then try next all it will work for the condition you have asked

Comment: yes it will but only in one row, i can't get to another td's if they are not in same row with nextAll

Comment: then you need to wrap your code in a  loop for all tables in one page see the updates that i have made